# How to access private variable in C++/CLI managed class

Tags: c++-cli

```
//MyWrapper.h
#include "arithmetic.h"
#include "mathematics.h"
namespace MyWrapper {
    public ref class ClassA
    {
    public:
        ClassA();
        ~ClassA();
        int add(int, int);
    private:
        MyEngine::Arithmetic *nativeClassA;
    }

    public ref class ClassB
    {
    public:
        ClassB(ClassA^ arith);
        ~ClassB();
        int pow(int, int);
    private:
        MyEngine::Mathematics *nativeClassB;
    }
}

//MyWrapper.cpp
#include "MyWrapper.h"
My::ClassA::ClassA()
{
    nativeClassA = new MyEngine::Arithmetic();
}
My::ClassA::~ClassA()
{
    delete nativeClassA;
}
int My::ClassA::add(int a, int b)
{
    return nativeClassA->add(a, b);
}
My::ClassB::ClassB(ClassA^ classA)
{
    nativeClassB = new MyEngine::Mathematics(classA->nativeClassA); //***Error***
}
My::ClassB::~ClassB()
{
    delete nativeClassB;
}
int My::ClassB::pow(int a, int b)
{
    int result = nativeClassB->pow(a, b);
    return result;
}
```

Here, Mathematics class need to init with Arithmetic class.
But nativeClassA is private variable in ClassA.
So `nativeClassB = new MyEngine::Mathematics(classA->nativeClassA);` , it will occurs compile error.

So I changed the nativeClassA to public.

But at that time, nativeClassA will export to c#.
I don't want to export nativeClassA variable to c#.

How can I fix it?
Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're writing a managed class, you can use all the access modifiers that C# has. This seems like a perfect scenario for [`internal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx). (The linked documentation is for C#, but it's the same keyword in C++/CLI.)

Comment: internal: MyEngine::Arithmetic *nativeClassA;like this?

Comment: The C++/CLI documentation is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke3a209d.aspx#BKMK_Member_visibility